# I want to extract all .tgz and .tar files in a single directory

Tags: python, path, extract

I'm using the following code to extract .tgz and .tar files into the same directory the archived files reside. It works fine with a single file. But, when I select another file in the same directory to extract, the current folder is overwritten (all of the files extract a root folder named storage). I imagine this is the reason why the files are being overwritten. So, I can only have one extracted file in the directory at any one time. I was trying to think of a clever way to extract the files into the same directory, maybe name the extracted file something unique once it's extracted. However, I'm a neophyte Python programmer and don't have the technical know-how or intellectual tool-set to accomplish such task at this time. Any help is appreciated. As it stands, I would have to select a different output directory every time I wanted to extract a file.

```
 import os, sys, tarfile



 def extract(tar_url, extract_path='.'):
     print tar_url
     tar = tarfile.open(tar_url, 'r')
     for item in tar:
         tar.extract(item, extract_path)
         if item.name.find(".tgz") != -1 or item.name.find(".tar") != -1:
             extract(item.name, "./" + item.name[:item.name.rfind('/')])

 userpath = "Extracted"
 directory = os.path.join("c:\\", userpath)
 try:
    for root, dirname, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file1 in files:
            if file1.endswith(".tgz") or file1.endswith(".tar"):
                extract(os.path.join(root, file1))
                print 'Done!'
 except:
    name = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
    print name[:name.rfind('.')], '<filename>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you maintain a global counter and append it to 'extract_path' in the extract() method each time a file is extracted? Once extracted (at the end of the extract() method) increment the counter.

```
import os, sys, tarfile

global counter
counter=1

def extract(tar_url, extract_path='.'):
     global counter
     print tar_url
     tar = tarfile.open(tar_url, 'r')
     for item in tar:
         tar.extract(item, extract_path+"_%d"%counter)
         counter+=1
         if item.name.find(".tgz") != -1 or item.name.find(".tar") != -1:
             extract(item.name, "./" + item.name[:item.name.rfind('/')])
```

Comment: Good idea, and it does create numbered directories .... However, the files only extract a folder now (they don't fully extract).

Answer (score 0):

If they don't have to be extracted all in the same directory, you can add a `os.chdir` to change your working directory to where the tar resides. `dirname` in your above script.

Else, you can extract each tar to a tmp dir and once the extract is complete, rename the dir to match the name of the file you extracted.

Comment: Thanks, but I have done that. I was really interested in keeping them in the same folder.

Comment: @user are there directories in the tar files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test this at the moment, but could you simply test to see if a folder exists with the item's name and then continue if so (basically this)

```
def extract(tar_url, extract_path='.'):
     print tar_url
     tar = tarfile.open(tar_url, 'r')
     for item in tar:
         if(os.path.isdir(os.path.join(extract_path,item.name))):
             continue;
         tar.extract(item, extract_path)
         if item.name.find(".tgz") != -1 or item.name.find(".tar") != -1:
             extract(item.name, "./" + item.name[:item.name.rfind('/')])
```

Comment: Hi C, it just extracts a file named storage and overwrites the file when I attempt to extract another .tgz file in the same directory.